# DBCC Physical only giving Connection failure

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, dbcc, dbcc-checkdb

I have a SQL server 2012 Ent DB.

The hosting company is trying to setup new backup solution using Symantec Backup Exec.

They have come back and said our database is corrupt because they get these errors:

> Consistency checking TrafficSmartCIT
>   Consistency Check Physical Only.
>   V-79-57344-65085 - There was a problem running the DBCC.
>   DBCC results for 'TrafficSmartCIT'.
>
> Consistency checking TrafficSmartCIT_ArcStats Consistency Check Physical Only.
>   V-79-57344-65085 - There was a problem running the DBCC.
>   Connection failure
>
> Consistency checking TrafficSmartCIT_HTML Consistency Check Physical Only.
>   V-79-57344-65085 - There was a problem running the DBCC.
>   Connection failure
>   ...

I have tried finding out what the "connection failure" bit is, as it sounds more network related then actual corruption.

I have run a `DBCC CHECKDB` on one of the DB's above that threw an error, and it had no errors.

Has anyone seen this sort of error before? And should I be concerned.

Comment: Try running a profiler when you are running a CHECKDB with PHYSICAL_ONLY to see whats going on. It might be due to N/W. If CHECKDB runs without errors on the DB, then you dont have to be worried.

Comment: Is this error happening consistently every time your hosting company runs the Symantec Backup Exec jobs? Or was this a one time event?